# How do I concatenate two slices in Rust?

Tags: rust

I want to take the x first and last elements from a vector and concatenate them. I have the following code:

```
fn main() {
    let v = (0u64 .. 10).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let l = v.len();
    vec![v.iter().take(3), v.iter().skip(l-3)];
}
```

This gives me the error

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> <anon>:4:28
  |
4 |     vec![v.iter().take(3), v.iter().skip(l-3)];
  |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::iter::Take`, found struct `std::iter::Skip`
<anon>:4:5: 4:48 note: in this expansion of vec! (defined in <std macros>)
  |
  = note: expected type `std::iter::Take<std::slice::Iter<'_, u64>>`
  = note:    found type `std::iter::Skip<std::slice::Iter<'_, u64>>`
```

How do I get my `vec` of `1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10`? I am using Rust 1.12.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should `collect()` the results of the `take()` and `extend()` them with the `collect()`ed results of `skip()`:

```
let mut p1 = v.iter().take(3).collect::<Vec<_>>();
let p2 = v.iter().skip(l-3);

p1.extend(p2);

println!("{:?}", p1);
```

**Edit**: as Neikos said, you don't even need to collect the result of `skip()`, since `extend()` accepts arguments implementing `IntoIterator` (which `Skip` does, as it is an `Iterator`).

**Edit 2**: your numbers are a bit off, though; in order to get `1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10` you should declare `v` as follows:

```
let v = (1u64 .. 11).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

Since the [`Range`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/struct.Range.html) is left-closed and right-open.

Comment: Thanks. Does the `<_>` mean something like "please infer the type"?

Comment: You don't need to collect `Skip` as `extend` can take an iterator

Comment: @TheUnfunCat Yes, `_` is a type placeholder

Answer (score 66):

Just use [`.concat()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.concat) on a slice of slices:

```
fn main() {
    let v = (0u64 .. 10).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let l = v.len();
    let first_and_last = [&v[..3], &v[l - 3..]].concat();
    println!("{:?}", first_and_last);
    // The output is `[0, 1, 2, 7, 8, 9]`
}
```

This creates a new vector, and it works with arbitrary number of slices.

[(Playground link)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c9414c870b2792b67eba9b959868f772&version=stable&backtrace=1)

Comment: Nice, but seem to require nightly

Comment: @Rawler Works fine nowadays with Rust 1.62.1.

Answer (score 24):

Ok, first of all, your initial sequence definition is wrong.  You say you want `1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10` as output, so it should look like:

```
    let v = (1u64 .. 11).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

Next, you say you want to concatenate *slices*, so let's actually use slices:

```
    let head = &v[..3];
    let tail = &v[l-3..];
```

At *this* point, it's really down to which approach you like the most.  You can turn those slices into iterators, chain, then collect...

```
    let v2: Vec<_> = head.iter().chain(tail.iter()).collect();
```

...or make a vec and extend it with the slices directly...

```
    let mut v3 = vec![];
    v3.extend_from_slice(head);
    v3.extend_from_slice(tail);
```

...or extend using more general iterators (which will become equivalent in the future with specialisation, but I don't believe it's as efficient *just yet*)...

```
    let mut v4: Vec<u64> = vec![];
    v4.extend(head);
    v4.extend(tail);
```

...or you could use `Vec::with_capacity` and `push` in a loop, or do the chained iterator thing, but using `extend`... but I have to stop at *some* point.

Full example code:

```
fn main() {
    let v = (1u64 .. 11).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let l = v.len();

    let head = &v[..3];
    let tail = &v[l-3..];

    println!("head: {:?}", head);
    println!("tail: {:?}", tail);

    let v2: Vec<_> = head.iter().chain(tail.iter()).collect();
    println!("v2: {:?}", v2);

    let mut v3 = vec![];
    v3.extend_from_slice(head);
    v3.extend_from_slice(tail);
    println!("v3: {:?}", v3);

    // Explicit type to help inference.
    let mut v4: Vec<u64> = vec![];
    v4.extend(head);
    v4.extend(tail);
    println!("v4: {:?}", v4);
}
```

Comment: `extend()` should shortly be specialized to `extend_from_slice()`; it was merged a few days ago: [Specialize Vec::extend to Vec::extend_from_slice](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/37094).

Comment: Stable release of which is... 9-ish weeks away?  Like I said, not *just yet.*

Comment: `let v = (1u64 .. 11).collect::<Vec<_>>();` booo. `let v: Vec<u64> = (1..11).collect();` yaaay

Comment: Why yes, just letting you know if you haven't seen that it was already merged.