# How can I concatenate adjacent slices in Rust

Tags: rust

I have two adjacent slices in memory. I know they are adjacent because I just created them from a single slice with `split_at`. I want to concatenate them together to get a slice covering the whole range again. Is there any way I can do that safely? Ideally, some function that takes multiple slices, sees if they are adjacent to each other, and merges them together if possible.

```rust
fn main() {
    let original_slice: &[u8] = &[1, 2, 3, 4];
    
    let (left, right) = original_slice.split_at(2);
    
    let rejoined_slice = todo!("take left and right and return an Option or similar")
    
    assert_eq!(original_slice, rejoined_slice);
    assert_eq!(original_slice.as_ptr(), rejoined_slice.as_ptr());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9e734d447dc166725ab2c0251dc525f1)

This is coming up for me using the `zerocopy` crate to do some zero-copy parsing. I sometimes end up with multiple slices of the same type that I know are next to each other (after all, I just parsed them, checked their alignment, etc.), and it would be useful to fuse them together.

Not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154150/how-do-i-concatenate-two-slices-in-rust): I don't want to end up with a new `Vec`, I want to fuse the already-adjacent slices in place without copying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually somewhat of a controversial topic: it is not decided whether this kind of capability should be possible at *all*, and the current consensus (from my interpretation of discussions) seems to lean against it. From the documentation in [`std::ptr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/index.html):

> #### Provenance
>
> **This section is non-normative and is part of the [Strict Provenance](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/95228) experiment.**
>
> Pointers are not simply an “integer” or “address”. For instance, it’s uncontroversial to say that a Use After Free is clearly Undefined Behaviour, even if you “get lucky” and the freed memory gets reallocated before your read/write (in fact this is the worst-case scenario, UAFs would be much less concerning if this didn’t happen!). To rationalize this claim, pointers need to somehow be more than just their addresses: they must have provenance.
>
> ...
>
> Shrinking provenance cannot be undone: even if you “know” there is a larger allocation, you can’t derive a pointer with a larger provenance. Similarly, you cannot “recombine” two contiguous provenances back into one (i.e. with a `fn merge(&[T], &[T]) -> &[T]`).

---

If it is ultimately decided that widening provenance is allowed, you could accomplish this with a bit of pointer operations:

```
/// SAFETY: Both parameters must refer to the same allocated object.
unsafe fn rejoin<'a, T>(a: &'a [T], b: &'a [T]) -> Option<&'a [T]> {
    if a.as_ptr().add(a.len()) == b.as_ptr() {
        Some(std::slice::from_raw_parts(a.as_ptr(), a.len() + b.len()))
    } else {
        None
    }
}
```

But note that I've still made the function `unsafe` and left a comment documenting so. Two slices could theoretically be adjacent while being separate objects. For example, `let a = [1, 2];` and `let b = [3, 4];` can reasonably be contiguous variables on the stack, but it would be undefined behavior to access them as a single slice. Because of this, the function should be `unsafe` and the caller must guarantee they are from the same originating object.

Comment: That makes sense. I can see why it's not safely possible, and I'm going to go with a fully-safe codepath that doubles up on some parsing work until I have evidence that I really need this. Thanks for the explanation and the example!